# Check presence of a column in multiple tables

Tags: kdb

I want to check if a column is present in multiple tables.
When I try for one table, it works.

```
`tickerCol in cols tradeTable / (output is 1b) hence working perfectly
`tickerCol in cols table2 / (output is 1b) hence working perfectly
```

but when I run

```
`ticker in cols @' (tradeTable;table2) / (output is 0b, expected output 11b)
```

for above example ticker column is present in both tables(tradeTable;table2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works using each-both `'`:

`` `ticker in ' cols each (tradeTable; table2) ``

This will find the columns that are present in each of the tables and then perform a check on each of the column lists to find if `` `ticker `` is present in these lists.

Comment: Could you please add some informations, how your solution works?

Comment: Another variant using each-right you might want to add  ->    q)`ticker in/:cols each `trade`trade2

Answer (score 2):

Solution is already provided in another answer. Just trying to explain why your solution is not working.

Lets  say we have 2 tables `t1` (columns `id` and `v1`) and  `t2` (columns `id` and `v2`).

Now when we run:

```
    q) cols@'`t1`t2
```

output will be a list of list:

```
(`id`v1;`id`v2)
```

This list has 2 entries where each entry is a list.

Now what you are doing is trying to find column in this list .

```
    q) `id in (`id`v1;`id`v2)   /output 0b
```

And since that list doesn't have `id` as an entry it returns `0b`.

If you search `` `id`v1 `` which is a list you will get `1b` matching first entry.

```
    q)  `id`v1 in (`id`v1;`id`v2)  / output 1b
```

What you want here is to search your column name in each entry of that list. So the only thing you are missing in your expression is each-both. This will work:

```
     q) `id in'cols@'`t1`t2   / output 11b
```

In your case it will be:

```
     q) `ticker in ' cols@'`tradeTable`table2
```